# Test assertResponseRedirects with relative path

Tags: php, html, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm fairly new to Symfony and testing in general and I don't understand why this test does not pass.

```
public function testLoginWithBadCredentials(): void
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form([
        '_username' => 'user@user.com',
        '_password' => 'wrongpassword',
        '_dob' => '25/06/1485'
    ]);
    $client->submit($form);

    $this->assertResponseRedirects('/login');
        
    //...
}
```

My login form is very basic:

```
<form action="{{ path('app_login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}">

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password">

    <label for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="_dob">

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/">

    {# Prevent Login CSRF attacks #}
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Got this error when I run the test:

```
Failed asserting that Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse Object &00000000000005450000000000000000 (
     ├     'headers' => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object &00000000000005170000000000000000 (
     ├         'headers' => Array &0 (
     ├             'cache-control' => Array &1 (
     ├                 0 => 'max-age=0, must-revalidate, private'
     ├             )
     ├             'date' => Array &2 (
     ├                 0 => 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 02:59:15 GMT'
     ├             )
     ├             'location' => Array &3 (
     ├                 0 => 'http://localhost/login'
     ├             )
     ├             'content-type' => Array &4 (
     ├                 0 => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
     ├             )
     ├             'x-robots-tag' => Array &5 (
     ├                 0 => 'noindex'
     ├             )
     ├             'expires' => Array &6 (
     ├                 0 => 'Wed, 22 Feb 2023 02:59:15 GMT'
     ├             )
     ├         )
     ├         'cacheControl' => Array &7 (
     ├             'max-age' => '0'
     ├             'must-revalidate' => true
     ├             'private' => true
     ├         )
     ├         'computedCacheControl' => Array &8 (
     ├             'max-age' => '0'
     ├             'must-revalidate' => true
     ├             'private' => true
     ├         )
     ├         'cookies' => Array &9 ()
     ├         'headerNames' => Array &10 (
     ├             'cache-control' => 'Cache-Control'
     ├             'date' => 'Date'
     ├             'location' => 'Location'
     ├             'content-type' => 'Content-Type'
     ├             'x-robots-tag' => 'X-Robots-Tag'
     ├             'expires' => 'Expires'
     ├         )
     ├     )
     ├     'content' => '<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n
     ├ <html>\r\n
     ├     <head>\r\n
     ├         <meta charset="UTF-8" />\r\n
     ├         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost/login'" />\r\n
     ├ \r\n
     ├         <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/login</title>\r\n
     ├     </head>\r\n
     ├     <body>\r\n
     ├         Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/login">http://localhost/login</a>.\r\n
     ├     </body>\r\n
     ├ </html>'
     ├     'version' => '1.1'
     ├     'statusCode' => 302
     ├     'statusText' => 'Found'
     ├     'charset' => 'UTF-8'
     ├     'targetUrl' => 'http://localhost/login'
     ├ ) is redirected and has header "Location" with value "/login".
```

The thing is, if I replace:

```
$this->assertResponseRedirects('/login');
```

with:

```
$this->assertResponseRedirects('http://localhost/login');
```

my test passes. I don't understand why the relative URI wouldn't work (and also I don't think I am supposed to have the absolute URI in my test, am I?).

Thanks :)